# How to setup a networked localhost server?

Tags: localhost, server, google-chrome-os

I have a PC, a chromebook and an ubuntu system on chromebook installed which I can switch with couple of keys. I want to run a common server to all three using either my chromebook (ubuntu) or my PC.

For example, on a single OS (like windows or ubuntu), I can install XAMPP or LAMP and do server programming. But I want to setup server on ubuntu on chromebook and access it in browser on chromeos.

I want this setup locally so I don't need to involve internet at all (just like we do in XAMPP/localhost)

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Oh I now actually see it. On chromeOS, when I'm running parallel linux to chromeOS, then actually, all the network activity done on ubuntu reflects back into chromeOS as well.

So if I'm listening on port 80 on ubuntu terminal, then it'll do the same on chrome as well!

Thanks!